# CSS border shorthand when each border has a different width

Tags: css, border, shorthand

Hi,

what is the shorthand for border when borders have different width?

I tried this:

```
border:1px solid black, 2px solid black, 3px solid black, 4px solid black;
```

and this:

```
 border:1px 2px 3px 4px, solid, solid, solid, solid, black, black, black, black;
```

but none of them work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use

```
border: solid black;
border-width: 1px 2px 3px 4px;
```

Comment: I see. I thought there was a one-line shorthand for that. Thank you.

Comment: border: solid black; should be written before border-width: 1px 2px 3px 4px; otherwise it is not going to work (so you cannot sort the css lines alphabetically).