# Shorthand for CSS border rule

Tags: html, css, border, shorthand

I was just wondering if there's a shorthand for this CSS rule. I guess it is not a good idea to define border first and then override it in the next line by specifying a different border-width.
Can we simplify it somehow?

```
div.container {
  border: 0 solid gray;
  border-width: 5px 2px;
}
```

Comment: why it's not good if it works? you have no other way if you want different border on each side, you need at least two declarations of more (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border)

Comment: You can remove the 0. But the rest has to stay the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately **there is no shorthand** for the border / border-wdith property if you don't set equals border width for all sides.

(See [CSS border shorthand when each border has a different width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437141/css-border-shorthand-when-each-border-has-a-different-width))

Example for equals border width :

```
div.container {
  border: 5px solid gray;
}
```

or with different border width (your case)

```
div.container {
  border: 0 solid gray;
  border-width: 5px 2px;
}
```